# Javascript synchronous CORS request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, synchronous, xdomainrequest

Because of the cookielaw in The Netherlands, it seems we all have te implement 'cookiewalls'. 
My idea is quite simple, at the top of the page (but only if it's in Dutch) I made a check, if a status cookie is set, if it is the page will continue to load, if not it redirects to another page which asks for permission. When permission is granted the page redirects to it's origin. This way I didn't have to rewrite the existing JavaScript code.

I also want to check if it's set for one of our other websites. I want to do that with an AJAX call. I have found this code:

```
function createCORSRequest(method, url) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    if ("withCredentials" in xhr) {
        xhr.open(method, url, true);
    } else if (typeof XDomainRequest != "undefined") {
        xhr = new XDomainRequest();
        xhr.open(method, url);
    } else {
        xhr = null;
    }
    return xhr;
}
```

But as with all AJAX calls, it's asynchronous but in this case it has to wait until the script knows for sure it is allowed to continue, if not it has to redirect.

This XMLHttpRequest is quite easy to make synchronous I know, but seems like it's not possible with the XDomainRequest. What's the best to halt all execution until there is a response of the XDomainRequest?

Comment: No, CORS cannot be synchronous. And even if they were, for your use case synchronous requests are an incredibly bad idea - just don't do this. They're deprecated for exactly this reason. Just continue immidiately, you still can redirect later.

Comment: I would like to do that, but that would mean that the site executes it's normal code with analytics and adwords, we can't do that until the user gives permission to do so.

Comment: Well then a) load analytics and ads asynchronously (later) b) use a cookie to store that the user has already given permission (that cookie could either be evaluated on server side, or synchronously on client side)

Comment: I'm already using a cookie, but i also have to know if they already gave permission on one of our other websites. But I'm afraid I have to load analytics and ads asynchronously.

Comment: I don't understand. Don't you use one single cookie that is either set on all of the websites or none of them?

Comment: Multiple websites with multiple purposes on multiple servers, as far as I know it's impossible to share cookies between those.

Comment: You can do it by including resources from the other domains that are loaded specifically and only for setting the cookie.